# Understand Knockout.js data binding

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, knockoutjs

I come across this code :

**app/code/Aheadworks/OneStepCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/onestep.html**

```
<div class="aw-onestep aw-onestep-sidebar" data-bind="mageInit: {'awOscSidebar':{}}">
    <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="aw-mobile-hide">
            <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-header">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Review'"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-content">
            <div class="aw-mobile-hide">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('cart-items') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!--/ko-->
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('totals') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-options') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->

            <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-block aw-sidebar-before-place-order">
                <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-block_title"></div>
                <div class="aw-onestep-sidebar-block_content">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('order-note') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('trustSeals') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

Questions :

- What is the `mageInit: {'awOscSidebar':{}}` mean? where this data coming from ?
- And where is the location of `getRegion()` and `getTemplate()` in the above code called in the backed side ?

Forgive me asking this basic question but I've been struggle understanding this code for hours, looking and searching this function in the code but no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.